# USB with partitions

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, usb, 20.04

I would like to do a full install of Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop on one volume of my USB (the OS one ofc). I found how to do it on a USB, but every tool I tried wants to format the whole drive and gets rid of the structure. How do I do this?

[image: Drive]

Comment: You haven't said if you want to install server or desktop Ubuntu. You can use *something-else* to install wherever you like rather than using the "*Erase disk and install* option.

Comment: I want to install the desktop Ubuntu, edited the question.

Comment: The something else is if you have an installation medium and then press install?

Comment: Are you booting your computer in UEFI mode or BIOS mode? If you have Windows 10 installed when you bought the computer, you are probably booting in UEFI mode, and then you cannot install Ubuntu completely into the 'OS' partition on your USB drive. If you allow the installer to tamper with your internal drive (and put files to boot Ubuntu into the EFI system partition), you can do it, but it will only work in the computer, where you installed it. If you want a portable USB drive with Ubuntu, you need another USB drive or allow Ubuntu to use at least two partitions in the current USB drive.

Comment: There might be another and severe problem: If Windows created **dynamic partitions** in your USB drive, Linux (and Ubuntu is a Linux distro) cannot manage it. Then you must use another USB drive (or overwrite the current one).